# Cannot change the font of the menu to bolder in Chrome DevTools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My website is at https://www.datanumen.com/

I want to change the font of the menu items to bolder, so I do as follows:

1. Open it in Chrome
2. Click "DevTools"
3. Go to the first menu item "Products" and right click "Inspect".
4. Then I find the menu item

```
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-161"><a href="https://www.datanumen.com/products/">Products</a></li>
```

5. Then in the right hand, I click "+" to add a style for it, as follows:

```
li.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

I hope to make all the menu items bolder, so I choose the specifier as specific as to the menu-item-object-page instead of menu-item-161.

Then after doing that, nothing happens. The menu items does not become bolder at all.

Below is what I do:
[image]

Just wonder what I do wrong? Thank you very much.

**Update**

Have just use the following css rule to bold the menu items:

```
#menu-main-menu-1 li a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But one more question is that it seems bold and bolder are completed same, see below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css you missed "a"

```
li.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page a {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Always choose id over classes as id's are unique so no confusion, as you have id in your ul tag

give the following css

```
#menu-main-menu-1 li a {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@alanac The font-familiy you are using must have support for that css property. I try with font-weight: 1000; and that's all bolder appearance that can be set for this font.

[testing wwww.datanumen.com in chrome browser with developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQPB4.png)

Answer (score 0):

`font-weight` applied to the child `a` element is taking precedence here. You should target the `a` element inside `li`, instead of `li`.

```css
li.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page a {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
.desktop-nav>ul>li>a {
    font-weight: 900 !important;
}
or
.desktop-nav>ul>li>a {
    font-weight: bolder !important;
}
```

The font weight should go to the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with answers, you are need target the 'a' element.

Check if it's not an inheritance applied from another css declaration.

[testing wwww.datanumen.com in chrome browser with developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euR7N.png)

[testing wwww.datanumen.com in chrome browser with developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRsJ9.png)